# Is there any way to prevent or detect char(0) from texts?

Tags: character, filemaker, nul

In some occasions, specially when copy-pasting, we end up having some text fields with a character 0 (nul) at the end of a string.

It doesn't show in any way when you display the data, but you do detect it when you export it.

[image: Exported text with null char]

We've tried to (at least) detect it by using the "Position" function.

However Position(text_field, char(0), 1, 1) won't find this char (it does return 0, even if the character is there).

I guess this is some kind of bug from FileMaker, but I'd like to know if anyone has found a way to circumvent it...

More info and a database sample at: https://community.claris.com/en/s/question/0D53w00005wrUMMCA2/character-0-0x0-in-text-fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the result of `Char(0)` is an empty string, not the expected control character.

You can generate the `null` character in a number of ways:

- `HexDecode ( "00" )`
- `Base64Decode ( "AA==" )`
- `ExecuteSQL ( "SELECT DISTINCT CHR(0) FROM SomeTable" ; "" ; "" )`

or paste it into a global field and get it from there.

Once you have the character, it's easy to detect it or just substitute it out.

---

You may want to bypass the entire issue by allowing only printable characters - see, for example: https://www.briandunning.com/cf/1291

Answer (score 0):

I run into this problem quite frequently when users try to copy-paste text from office programs into FileMaker fields on windows (my guess is that FileMaker for some reason can't handle Microsoft Office line endings properly).

The most efficient solution I found is to use auto enter calculation or script with Filter() function, in order to remove any unwanted characters.

Alterntively if you have access to plug-ins you can try using the MBS ("Text.RemoveControlCharacters") function from Monkeybread FileMaker plug-in which is uspposed to remove all characters with code 32 or lower.

Comment: The `Filter()` function does not "remove any unwanted characters". It removes all characters except the wanted ones. Which makes it problematic for solutions that support multiple alphabets.